# Mocking an array exposed as a property

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've been given some code with this general structure:

```
public class A
{
    int Foo { get; set; }
    byte Bar { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    A[] _Baz = new A[10];

    A[] Baz
    {
        get { return _Baz; }
        set { _Baz = value; }
    }
}
```

I know, I know exposing an array, not great but it's what I've been give to work with.

Anyhow I'm looking to mock class B and set some of the array elements to specific values to be used by the consuming code.

It would seem that moq isn't able to do this directly but I have seen suggestions to mock an array of class A and return that via the class B mock. Kind of Like this:

```
var mockAArray = new Mock<A>[10];
mockAArray[3] = new Mock<B>();

var mockB = new Mock<B>();
mockB.Setup(x => x.A).Returns(mockAArray);
```

I say kind of because that doesn't actually work, I know I should be trying to return something like `mockAArray.Object` but I can't quite find the correct syntax to get this working.

Edit:
Using the answer supplied by dee the correct syntax for the above example would be:

```
IA[] tmpAArray = new A[10];
var mockA = new Mock<IA>;
mockA.Setup(x => x.Foo).Returns(1234);
tmpAArray[3] = mockA.Object;

var mockB = new Mock<IB>;
mockB.Setup(y => y.Baz).Returns(tmpAArray);
```

End Edit

Ultimately I'd like to refactor the code to get rid of the exposed array but I'd also like to get this test in place to help catch any breakages along the way

Edit:
Ok I've been asked for a more complex situation where I'd want to think about doing this. So here's another slightly more convoluted, and please keep in mind not real, example.

```
public class MySerialPort : ISerialPort
{
    SerialPort _port;
    ... // properties exposing _port properties

    MySerialPort()
    {
        _port = new SerialPort;
    }

    void Open()
    {
        _port.Open();
    }

    void Close()
    {
        _port.Close();
    }
    ... // more methods 
}

public class PortManager
{
    ISerialPort[] ports = new MySerialPort[10];

    ISerialPort[] Port
    {
        get { return ports; }
        set { ports = value; }
    }

    ... // properties for managing the ports

    ... // some methods for good measure
}

public class TestClass()
{
    int SomeMagicRoutine(PortManager manager)
    {
        // Some routine that takes the values in manager
        // and the values in ports and returns an answer.
    }
}
```

Just spinning up a real array of MySerialPort and manager instances would make testing difficult, imagine if were an array of Streams instead, not nice. This is why I would prefer to mock. Obviously for the most simple cases just using real instances would be fine, unfortunately the real world doesn't always allow us to take the easy option.

Anyway the original simple example was an attempt to be succinct.

Comment: Why can't you create a real class (like `class MockB`) with the properties you need ? (What if you just dropped moq)

Comment: The actual class I'm trying to mock is more complex than the example, so I removed the extra complexity for the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are using the class `B` in your `Class Under Test (CUT)`. If you have some possibility how to inject the instance of class `B` into CUT then you do not need mock.

For example with constructor injection you would have sometheing like this.

```
public class CUT
{
    private B _b;

    public CUT(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void test01()
{
    // Arrange
    // here you create your fake-array
    A[] bazFake = new A[] { new A { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 } };

    B bFake = new B();
    bFake.Baz = bazFake;

    // and inject this fake-object into the CUT
    CUT cut = new CUT(bFake);

    // Act
    // ...

    // Assert
    // ...
}
```

Edit:

Then the easiest way to use `Moq` would be to create an `IPortManager` interface:

```
public interface IPortManager
{
    ISerialPort[] Port { get; set; }

    // properties for managing the ports

    // some methods for good measure
}
```

Then the class `PortManager` will implement it:

```
public class PortManager : IPortManager
{ ... }
```

And then in the test mock the `IPortManager` and `ISerialPort` and use it in CUT:

```
ISerialPort[] fakePorts = new MySerialPort[10];

// create your fake ports here and setup methods according to your needs
int openedPorts = 0; // just an example, I don't know what you are going to test
Mock<ISerialPort> port1Stub = new Mock<ISerialPort>();
port1Stub.Setup(p => p.Open()).Callback(() => openedPorts++);
fakePorts[0] = port1Stub.Object; 

Mock<IPortManager> managerStub = new Mock<IPortManager>();
managerStub.Setup(m => m.Port).Returns(fakePorts);

TestClass cut = new TestClass();
cut.SomeMagicRoutine(managerStub.Object);
```

Comment: Excellent, that last section of code did the trick. I'll update my question to show your method against the original simple example.